# Results to pull out selected category from a gallery - php sql

Tags: php, html, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a gallery page on my website I'm working on, which when landed on it just shows ALL of the categories, (I just `SELECT * FROM tblImages`, however I have now added on a filter and I want the users then to be able to select which photography category they would like to see appear in the gallery.

My code so far (my drop down list):

```
<div class="grid-2">                
    <form action = "" method = "POST">
     <label>Competition Categories</label>
     <select name="catID">
     <option value="">Select</option>
     <option value="1">Black & White</option>
     <option value="2">Urban</option>
     <option value="3">Natural World</option>
     <option value="4">Anything Goes</option>
     <option value="5">Straight Out Of The Camera</option>
     <option value="6">Landscape</option>
     </select>
     </fieldset>
    <button name="view-cat" type="submit" type="button">View</button>
   </form>
</div>
```

My Gallery code with my query to show ALL images at first:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="grid-full">
        <h1><u>GALLERY</u></h1>                 
            <div class="masonry">
            <?php
            $query = "SELECT * FROM `tblImage`";
            $result = $conn -> query($query);
            while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc())
            {
            ?>

            <div class="item">
            <a href="<?php echo $row['fldFilePath']; ?>" data-lightbox="gallery" data-title="<?php echo $row['fldName']; ?>"><img alt src="<?php echo $row['fldFilePath']; ?>" class="ImgRound"></a>
            <button class="update-title-btn">Update</button>
            <button class="delete-img-btn">Delete</button>
            </div>

            <?php
            }
            ?>
```

Do you know how I would then run a query to `SELECT * FROM tblImage WHERE fldCatID =1;` depending on if the user did choose to select something from the drop down list??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just make a query like this:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['view-cat']){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `tblImage` WHERE fldCatID ='".$_POST['catID']."'";    
    $result = $conn -> query($query);
    while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc())
    {
```

`... the code will loop`

```
    }
}else{
$query = "SELECT * FROM `tblImage` ";    
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    while($row = $result-> fetch_assoc())
    {
```

`... the code will loop if no selection`

```
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. Can I ask though will ALL of the images show at first when there has been no selection still with that?

Comment: @K.Haydock you can make if else >> if (there a selection) `select * wehre` and else `select *`

Comment: @A.E-zahaby so It works but shows NO images at all when landing on the page now, until category is clicked, is there anyway you could show what you mean by if none selected show all, else just show 'x' category? :-)

Answer (score 2):

First you need to make sure the category ID is set and is numeric (to avoid SQL Injection):

```
$catID = (isset($_POST['catID']) && is_numeric($_POST['catID'])) ? $_POST['catID'] : false;
```

Then you can run the query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `tblImage`" . (($catID) ? " WHERE fldCatID $catID" : "");
```

Using the ternary operator `(($catID) ? " WHERE fldCatID $catID" : "")` will only select a category if one is set by the user.

Comment: Hi @DanielG do you know the other way to do  this via the prepared statement?

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't like my variable: `$catID = $_POST['catID'];`
$stmt = $conn->prepare ("SELECT * FROM `tblImage` WHERE `fldCatID` = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $catID);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();

Comment: Het @DanielG thanks for the reply, I realised the if else above code wasn't working as when the user landed on the page, the catID wouldn't be set on page load, so I added a:
if(isset($_POST['catID'])) {
$catID = $_POST['catID'];
}

Comment: @K.Haydock The equivalent code is listed in the answer, I just opted for a ternary operator instead of an `if` statement. Use whatever you're most comfortable with.

Comment: Thanks @DanielG I haven't come across these being a newbie but I'll defo look into these, thank you again for your help!! :-)